# AppDomain in Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, appdomain

I have tried to create an AppDomain within Azure Functions to run untrusted code. Creating the domain seems to work fine, but when I try to load in assemblies, it seems like they get loaded in incorrectly.

First I tried a simple AppDomain:

```
public class Sandboxer
{
    public void Run()
    {
        AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("name");
        var obj = newDomain.CreateInstance(typeof(OtherProgram).Assembly.FullName, typeof(OtherProgram).FullName).Unwrap();
    }
}

public class OtherProgram : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        foreach (var item in args)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

I got an error

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Sandboxer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2cd9cb1d6fdb50b4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I then tried to set the appliactionBase to the folder with my dll in it.

```
public class Sandboxer
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var location = typeof(OtherProgram).Assembly.Location;
        AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup();
        ads.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
        AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("name", null, ads);
        var obj = newDomain.CreateInstance(typeof(OtherProgram).Assembly.FullName, typeof(OtherProgram).FullName).Unwrap();
        var other = obj as OtherProgram;
        var other2 = obj as MarshalByRefObject;
    }
}

public class OtherProgram : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        foreach (var item in args)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

In this case, "other" is null at the end of the Run() method, but "other2" is a __TransparentProxy. It seems like it is finding and loading the dll, but doesn't understand the type.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Cross posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/59b119d8-1e51-4460-bf86-01b96ed55b12/how-can-i-create-an-appdomain-in-azure-functions?forum=AzureFunctions&prof=required

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/59b119d8-1e51-4460-bf86-01b96ed55b12/how-can-i-create-an-appdomain-in-azure-functions?forum=AzureFunctions). Please avoid cross posting without explicit pointers in both directions, so that people don't try to answer something that already has been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppDomains are not usable with Azure Functions. In order to properly sandbox code in Azure Functions, you would have to create a new Azure Functions App and run the code there.

If you are allowing users to write scripts, you can use another language like Lua that allows easy sandboxing.

Answer (score 1):

> In this case, "other" is null at the end of the Run() method, but "other2" is a __TransparentProxy. It seems like it is finding and loading the dll, but doesn't understand the type.

According to your description, I could encounter the similar issue, I tried to create a Console application to check this issue and found that the code could work as expected under a Console application.

For Azure Function, `obj as OtherProgram` always returns null. Then I tried to instantiate `OtherProgram` under the current domain as follows:

```
var obj=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(typeof(OtherProgram).Assembly.Location, typeof(OtherProgram).FullName);
OtherProgram op = obj as OtherProgram;
if (op != null)
    op.PrintDomain(log);
```

The above code could work as expected, but I did not found why the object under a new AppDomain always returns null. You may try to add a issue under [Azure/Azure-Functions](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues).

Comment: I'll add a bug there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in a conventional .NET application, should work in Azure Functions:

1. Register to the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event on the newly created AppDomain
2. In the event handler, resolve the assembly path using the [Function Directory / Function App Directory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function) in order to point to the *bin* folder

Comment: var d = ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory + "\bin" gives me the same directory as I am using in the second example. I tried using the AssemblyResolve function doing return Assembly.Load(typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.FullName), but I get the same results as in my second example.